# Can not position element (div) to the left

Tags: css, tumblr

I am trying to position a div more to the left, but no matter what I try, nothing seems to work. I have tried every property / style I can think of, and nothing works for me.

I have tried left, position, margin, padding and may others. I initially thought there might be a center causing this, but I just can't seem to find anything. I have debugged this in firebug and there just doesn't seem to be anything that I can see causing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - all I want to do is position this element a little more to the left, say 5-10px.

You can see the problematic div on this website http://girlswithbraces.co At the bottom, there is a section with the social buttons that I can't for the life of me get to shift a little more to the left.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your `ul.socialicons` elements wit the firebug, it seems you have a padding-left of 40px, but it seems to be impossibile reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#socialIcons { margin-left: -5px; }` works.

Comment: Thank you. I normally try this and it must have just slipped my mind today!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
float:left
```

to the first div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove all margins and paddingss first atleast to see if it is a problem with one of those.
Just put

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

If you can move it after that it means that it is a problem of a margin or a padding of something. You can find that "something" afterwards.